To keyframe camera using your mouse or 3dconnexion Space Mouse (or similar)

Icon on right side -> Click 'Toggle the camera view'
View menu on right side -> Click 'Camera to View'
Below timeline, Click 'Auto Keying'


Here's two basic methods for camera movement that can be used as needed to achieve your end vision.
Method 1 to get a rough-draft real-time camera movement:
If you press play on the timeline you can move the camera around in real-time with your mouse or 3dconnexion Space Mouse (what I use and recommend for any 3D) and capture keyframe motion like if you are really moving your camera around on a movie set. Since keyframes are going to be continuously created with even the slightest touch of the mouse or Space Mouse, after you finish real-time keyframing, just go back and delete all of the extra keyframe that cause undesired camera motion.
Method 2 for creating specific camera positions for basic/simpler camera motion:
Without the timeline playing, just go to specific frames and position the camera as needed using your mouse or Space Mouse

Did you have a question somewhere in this post? I'm not sure I see it.

Is there a place to post tips? This info I posted was a compilation of information I found scattered on the web, so I wanted to post it here in one place.

If you've seen a question here which you can answer, please answer it but don't simply post answers into a question field. This is not the place for posting tips on their own!
